# Power management does not recognize removal of power supply!

Tags: windows, indicator, power-management, lenovo, gnome-power-manager

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Battery management doesn't recognize removal of power supply](https://askubuntu.com/questions/164894/battery-management-doesnt-recognize-removal-of-power-supply)

I have a Lenovo Ideapad Z370 with Ubuntu 11.10 and the battery status indicator shows wrong information.

## Problem:

The indicator always shows that the power supply is connected, even if it's not connected. The battery charges and discharges normally. However, the status information is wrong. When charging, the "time to charge" decreases, and when discharging the "time to charge" increases.

If the power supply is connected the power statistics show:

- "Supply Yes"
- "Online Yes"

If it is not connected it shows:

- "Supply Yes"
- "Online No"

## My trials:

I tried reinstalling the indicator applet, but that doesn't help.
Searching for solutions or similar problems didn't point out any help.

## Background:

The problem occured after I switched the battery mode in Windows. (I use a dual boot system.) Lenovo drivers allow a "battery runtime mode" for maximum runtime and a "battery health mode" for maximum battery lifetime. I initially used the runtime mode, tried the health mode for some time, but switched back to the runtime mode. The problem occured after switching to health mode.

---

Does anyone have an idea what is wrong?

The problem is relevant for me as I get no information when battery status low and the computer runs out of energy without shutdown or hibernation. This is really a problem for me!